# How to select only within specific range when using JOIN?

Tags: sql, join

I want to join two tables, but from the first table, I want to select only data which belong to the given date range.

```
Product
-------
name, mrp, link, dateCreated
book 1, 30, http://.., 1583020800000
book 2, 40, http://.., 1583107200000

Event
-----
name, url, count
book 2, http://.., 3
book 5, http://..
```

I want to join both tables and select all products in the month of March `[1583020800000, 1585699200000)`

```
select name, mrp, url from product left join event on product.link = event.url AND mrp > 0 AND dateCreated >= 1583020800000 AND dateCreated < 1585699200000
```

The above SQL returns all rows from the first table. The AND conditions are not working. How to query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
select name, mrp, url 
from product left join event on product.link = event.url 
where product.mrp > 0 AND dateCreated >= 1583020800000 AND dateCreated < 1585699200000
```

If you use left join, you get each result of left side of a join (the product) and get null for the right side.

If you add a where condition, then you filter the joined results.

Pay attention to index. If you have a lot of record, an index on dateCreated speed up the query.